# Issue with generating left click in win32 api?

Tags: winapi, mouseleftbuttondown

Below is my code to generate left click using win32 api. The problem is that it gets stuck and does not return to main. When i press Ctrl+c, then it returns to main. **BUT** when I call it twice, to simulate double click then it is fine. Is there anything wrong with this code?
Thank you.

```
void LeftClick(void)
{  
  INPUT    Input={0};

  // left down 
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE; /*The event is a mouse event. Use the mi structure of the union.*/
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
  SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));

  // left up
  ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
  Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
  Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
  SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Comment: When you run in the debugger, on what line does it get stuck?

Comment: When i do debugging it is fine, i do not see it getting stuck any where. But when i run it then it gets stuck! so confusing.

Comment: You are clicking on stuff, it could have any kinds of side effects.  Depending on where the mouse is at.

Comment: @rashid: Try printf debugging then.  Once you isolate where it gets stuck, you can start to understand why.

Comment: @Ben, thanks for the advice, doing that pointed the problem to ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));

Comment: @rashid: That's very unusual.  Do you still have a problem if you use `memset` instead?  Or you could use an array of 2 INPUT structures and send both with a single `SendInput` call.

Comment: ok so sometimes it gets stuck at SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT)); and sometimes at that ZeroMemory(...). I have no idea.

Comment: The ZeroMemory can't be to blame. That said it's pointless, but it can't explain this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not committed to using SendInput, I've had success in the past using SendMessage on the desired hWnd with WM_LBUTTONDOWN then again with WM_LBUTTONUP.

Most buttons also simulate a click with keyboard entry. You can use SendMessage to your desired hWnd with WM_KEYDOWN and wParam VK_SPACE, then WM_KEYUP with VK_SPACE to complete the space bar keypress simulation.